# When editing the record that uses Carrierwave, I get a 'has thumb_image_changed' error even though I am not updating any images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

This is the error I get when I try to update a non-image attribute of a record on my `Vendor` model (e.g. the `owner`):

```
NoMethodError at /admin/vendor/12/edit

Message undefined method `thumb_image_changed?' for #<Vendor:0x007ff47d097468>
File    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@my-app/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb
Line    407
```

So, this error is generated even though I am not changing the image.

This is what my `Vendor` model looks like:

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :banner_image, :logo_image, :intro_text, :thumb_image, :category_ids, :product_ids, :user_id, :remove_banner_image, :banner_image_cache, :remove_logo_image, :logo_image_cache
    mount_uploader :banner_image, ImageUploader
    mount_uploader :logo_image, ImageUploader
    mount_uploader :thumb_image, ImageUploader

has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :categories, :through => :products
belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User",
    :foreign_key => "user_id"   
end
```

I think I get a similar error when I try to update just one of the images of a record (and not all 3).

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

The `Vendor#update` controller looks like a normally scaffolded `update` action:

```
  def update
    @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vendor.update_attributes(params[:vendor])
        format.html { redirect_to @vendor, notice: 'Vendor was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @vendor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here are the params that generate this request:

```
Started PUT "/vendors/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-06 16:51:28 -0500
Processing by VendorsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3bl5Q=", "vendor"=>{"name"=>"Die", "intro_text"=>"Toppa top jeans", "description"=>"The best jeans you can get your legs in."}, "commit"=>"Update Vendor", "id"=>"12"}
  Category Load (13.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" LIMIT 6
  Vendor Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "12"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms
```

The attribute I was updating in this case is the `name` attribute.

Also, for what it's worth, here is a full [stack trace of this request](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/941#issuecomment-11934964).

Comment: Could you add the code of your controller where you're updating the record ? And eventually could you also show us what do the params look like when you get that error ?

Comment: @pjam - Just added both. Look forward to your thoughts :)

Comment: Are you sure your vendors table has a column named `thumb_image` ? Because it really looks like ActiveModel::Dirty (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) is trying to run the `..._changed?` method on an existing column

Comment: Hrmm..... @pjam...now that I think about it, you may be right. I am looking through my `schema.rb` and am not seeing it.

Comment: Yes @pjam...that seems to have been the issue. If you add that as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks much!!

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing that right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your `vendors` table has a column named `thumb_image` ? Because it really looks like [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) is trying to run the `..._changed?` method on an existing column

Comment: Perfect. I had updated this model before, but didn't remove the `mount_uploader` call to my `thumb_image` column. So that was tripping everything up. For what it's worth, care to take a shot at this question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187248/activerecordhasmanythroughnestedassociationsarereadonly-error-in-rails-3-2-10