# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly Exception: Cannot modify association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

NOTE:
Yes, I know that there is supposedly duplicate posts on this matter, but the latest one that I saw is from *10 years ago* ([Link to that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187248/activerecordhasmanythroughnestedassociationsarereadonly-error-in-rails-admin)), was never solved, and none of the posts had gotten an answer that could solve my issue, thus here I am...

I have been trying to make an mock website where an `User` can make Binders, that hold Decks, which hold Flashcards.

My problem here is (most likely) with my joins table, the `Flashcard`.  `Flashcard` is my joins table because I am trying to also create an page where an `User` can browse through all of the Flashcards made by every *User*, and add it to one of their Decks (basically, shared access).

Every time I try to create an `Flashcard`, I get this error:

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly Exception: Cannot modify association 'User#flashcards' because it goes through more than one other association.

Here is my code:

`User` model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password

    has_many :binders
    has_many :decks, through: :binders
    has_many :flashcards, through: :decks
end
```

`Binder` model:

```rb
class Binder < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :decks
    has_many :flashcards, through: :decks
end
```

`Deck` model:

```rb
class Deck < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :binder
    has_many :flashcards
end
```

`Flashcard` model:

```rb
class Flashcard < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :deck

    validates :user, :deck, presence: true
end
```

`flashcards_controller.rb`:

```rb
class FlashcardsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        flashcard = set_user.flashcards.new(flashcard_params)
        flashcard.user_id = user.id
        if flashcard.save
            render json: flashcard, status: :created
        else
            render json: {errors: flashcard.errors.full_messages}, status: :unauthorized
        end
    end

    private
    def flashcard_params
        params.require(:flashcard).permit(:id, :user_id, :deck_id, :question, :answer) # Verify if the user_id is needed from frontend
    end
end
```

My `schema.rb`:

```rb
create_table "binders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "decks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "binder_id"
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "flashcards", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "deck_id"
    t.string "question"
    t.string "answer"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "password_digest"
  end
```

Comment: Does anybody have any possible solutions to this mess???  This is for an project of mine, and my deadline is in less than an week here.

Comment: I'm confused, you're saying that a User has_many flashcards through decks, but Flashcards appear to belong_to a User? Does your Flashcard table have an actual `user_id` field in it? If so, why are you doing a through relationship when it's a direct relationship? Please post the relevant parts of the schema for these tables so we can see the actual relations between them apart from what is configured in the models.

Comment: Okay, so I've added the `schema.rb` relationships in.

I just made some edits to my code, and I'm now able to create Flashcard objects, but loading the page has now gotten a lot slower...

Comment: I'm even more confused now. You said you made changes to your code but the edit history here doesn't show that you have added those changes to this question. You said your problem has been solved and you no longer get the error, so I assume that you no longer have this question? Either way, if what you have shown here is accurate then you have a *direct* relationship between flashcards and users -- most likely an actual database-level foreign key relationship -- and you shouldn't be bothering with users having flashcards *through* anything. Any other issues need to be in a new question.

Comment: I had thought that I got it solved, but it turns out, I still need to refresh the page to get the new Flashcard to render.  Otherwise, it is solved now...

I'll try to submit it as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out how to fix this issue...

My updated `flashcards_controller.rb` `create` method:

```
def create
    deck = current_user.decks.find_by(id: params[:deck_id])
    flashcard = deck.flashcards.new(flashcard_params)
    flashcard.user_id = current_user.id
    if flashcard.save
        render json: flashcard, status: :created
    else
        render json: {errors: flashcard.errors.full_messages}, status: :unauthorized
    end
end
```

This new `create` method works, because after the `Flashcard` object is created (but before attempting to save it), the method will keep checking for the new `Flashcard` object until it is found, assigns the `user_id` to it, and *then* attempts to save the new object...

Comment: I don't think you need that `if flashcard` in line 4 but it looks good otherwise